# Loop Cut with ctrl R doesnt work for me

Tags: shortcut

When I try to add a Loop Cut with Ctrl R it simply doesnt work. It worked yesterday but when I opened Blender today it didnt work at all. Tried to reopen it but that didnt help. Im sure I havent changed any settings so the Shortcut should still be Ctrl R. I am trying it in edit mode and use the newest Blender version. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you accidentally change the shortcut?

Comment: Did you change the topology? In such cases it may not work.

Comment: Does it not work even on the default cube?

Comment: In some cases other softwares can override the shortcuts. For example if I install the Radeon Adrealin driver alt+r no longer works in Blender, till I turn it off in the Radeon settings.